# How can I make the 'above RenderBody' and 'below RenderBody' content of a view available as separate 'header' and 'footer' files?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, umbraco

**Note: I figured out a solution before posting this question, so I will be replying to myself with my solution.**

I have a .NET MVC website that is using views set up in a hierarchy, passing data to each other via Section and RenderSection. I have a single top-level view called "Master" with several views inheriting from it.

I have two different external applications that I need to be able to dynamically import the 'outer template' of the MVC website as separate Header and Footer files, corresponding to the code above and below the "RenderBody" line of the top-level view, respectively.

How can I set things up so that I can retain my hierarchical view structure in the MVC app, and also provide these separate Header and Footer code files to the external applications?

I have tried moving the Master.cshtml code above and below RenderBody into Header and Footer partial views, with the intention of using those partial views both in Master.cshtml and also new Header.cshtml and Footer.cshtml files intended for use by the external applications. The problem is that I haven't found a way to make this work with the RenderSection lines that are mixed in with the Master.cshtml code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I found:

In Master.cshtml:

```
ViewDataDictionary globalHeaderData = new ViewDataDictionary {
    {"sectionName1", RenderSection("sectionName1", false)},
    {"sectionName2", RenderSection("sectionName2", false)},
};

ViewDataDictionary globalFooterData = new ViewDataDictionary {
    {"sectionName3", RenderSection("sectionName3", false)},
    {"sectionName4", RenderSection("sectionName4", false)},
};

@Html.Partial("GlobalHeader", Model, globalHeaderData)
@RenderBody()
@Html.Partial("GlobalFooter", Model, globalFooterData)
```

Then in GlobalHeader and GlobalFooter, replace each RenderSection line with this:

`@ViewData["theSectionName"]`

That's it!